# Sending two different email alerts based on Sales orders

Tags: process-builder, email-template, email-alert

I am trying to create a process builder rule that does the below.

When a new sales order is created - Send out a new email alert template.

If the order quantity is changed - Send out an updated SO email template

Nothing I have tried for hours on end seems to work. I can get the first part working in a number of ways which sends out the email when the order is newly created. But I cant find anything I can use that deters any difference between a new SO and an updated/Existing SO.

Comment: Can you please **[edit]** your post to include some of what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

1.Please make sure your PB fires on record create/edit

2.Add a new entry criteria for your "order quantity changed" event -> add the criteria as "ISCHANGED order quantity IS TRUE"

Comment: hi Chaps. Many thanks for your feedback. I fixed it now. I used ISNEW() for the first criteria, then for the second criteria. ISCHANGED.

I didnt know you could just use a plain formula by itself. I was trying to constantly refer it to a mapped field rather than just the entire object/SO